# Google Tokens after a while have invalid permission

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API in my Node.js app to fetch events from a user's calendar. I am using the `googleapis` package and have followed the steps to authenticate and authorize the API.

Everything was working fine for the first few days, but now I am receiving the following error message when trying to fetch events:

```json
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, as I have not made any changes to my code or the way I am using the API. I have tried refreshing the access token, but this did not resolve the issue.

Here's the relevant code I am using:

```js
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
const OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

const auth = new OAuth2(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, redirect);
auth.forceRefreshOnFailure = true;
// tokens is from DB where are stroed as they come as a response from Google
auth.setCredentials(tokens);

// Check if calendar is available
const from = new Date();
const to = new Date(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + +from);
try {
  const freeBusyQuery = {
    requestBody: {
        items: [{ id: 'primary' }],
        timeMin: from.toISOString(),
        timeMax: to.toISOString(),
    },
    fields: 'calendars,groups,kind,timeMax,timeMin',
    alt: 'json',
    auth: auth.client,
  };
  const response = await calendar.freebusy.query(freeBusyQuery);
  return !!response.data;
} catch (error) {
  // Couple days works ok and after always get error on this request with stored Token
  console.error(error);
  return false;
}
```

And an example of body for auth:

```js
const options = {
  access_type: 'offline',
  prompt: 'consent',
  include_granted_scopes: true,
  scopes: 'openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
}
```

I am using version 95.0.0 of the `googleapis` package.

Publishing status of consent screen is **In production.**

Can someone help me understand why I am receiving the `permission_denied` error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: delete the file tokens and make sure that your app requests authorization again.   let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Can you `JSON.stringify` your error before you log it? That way, we can see the full error details instead of just `[ [Object] ]`